# spring-integration-aws: SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter threads waiting for each other when calling stop()

Tags: spring, spring-integration, spring-cloud-aws

I was trying to stop the `SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter` when calling `stop()` I was receiving the following error:

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: null
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:205)
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.stop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:197)
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doStop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:133)
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.stop(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:329)
at org.springframework.cloud.aws.messaging.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.stop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1)
at org.springframework.integration.aws.inbound.SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.doStop(SqsMessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:140)
at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractEndpoint.stop(AbstractEndpoint.java:111)
```

First indications I thought it was a time out was not long enough, after looking into the issue I found the stopping thread and the running thread are waiting for each other and the `TimeoutException` would always happen. I fixed this by the follow piece of code:

```
new Thread() {
     public void run()
     {
        sqsMessageRawDataChannelAdapter.stop();
        LockSupport.parkNanos(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toNanos(5));
     }
  }.start();
```

I now no longer get the `TimeoutException` as the thread is able to stop. Have I done something wrong, or is this an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

M-m-m. Looks like a deadlock in your code.

You try to stop an adapter (and therefore listener) from thread which is held by the listener.

In your terms `stopping thread == running thread`.

To avoid such a problem you definitely should shift the `stop` operation to different Thread.